# Why was the [[unlikely]] attribute used in this example?

Tags: c++, cpu, c++20, c++-chrono, micro-optimization

I was reading https://iq.opengenus.org/cpp-likely-and-unlikely-attributes/ and I don't understand/agree with few things.

1. In the following code:

   ```
   void doModulus( vector<int> &vec , int mod ){

     // here the value of mod we are passing is 224, vec is of size 1024 holding values in [1,255]

     for( int i = 0 ; i<vec.size() ; i++ )
     {
         if( vec[i] >= mod ) [[unlikely]]{
             // so we are prioritizing  else statement here
             vec[i] = vec[i] % mod ;

         }else {

             vec[i] = vec[i] ;                         
         }
     }
   }
   ```

does it matter or make any difference if we make the else code `[[likely]]` or this happens automatically in background as if one side is likely then the other side isn't? (Although I would like it to be that if the one side is unlikely then the other side (if it was likely) to be strongly likely.

2. The following claim was made:

> % operation is a computationally heavy operation for cpu , so let's
> try to optimize our code.

While the "optimize" refers to adding the if else conditions, but I tested the code using `chrono` and it seems execution time was 2-3 times faster without if-else...

Plus I don't see why % is heavy, it's just about reading bottom bits of number.

Comment: Modulo is the remainder of a division which is algorithmically non-trivial. How fast or slow it is depends on the platform. But branches have their own cost associated. If modulo is too slow, and you only care about inspecting certain bits, consider using bitwise-and to mask those bits instead which is a simple operation which should be one of the fastest operations on most architectures. Either way, I wouldn't worry about it unless the performance is problematic.

Comment: The remainder from dividing by 224 is _not_ "just about reading bottom bits of number".  There are no bottom bits that will indicate the result of `% 224`.

Comment: @DrewDormann %2 is most right bit, %4 most right 2 bits...

Comment: Can someone answer 1 too?

Comment: _While the "optimize" refers to adding the if else conditions, but I tested the code using chrono and it seems execution time was 2-3 times faster without if-else..._ honestly it is more interesting that the rest of your question, but it is not answerable without Minimum Reproducible Example; still my wild guess is that you may want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/2945027

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: On some CPUs, it can be worth branching to avoid hardware division, even if it mispredicts a lot, like 25% or maybe even 50%.  On the latest Intel CPUs (Ice Lake etc.) with higher throughput integer dividers, the break-even mispredict rate is probably lower.  Probably not worth it just to avoid a multiplicative inverse (modulo by a constant), even when it's signed `int` that requires extra work, unless the pattern is quite predictable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does it matter or make any difference if we make the else code [[likely]] or this happens automatically in background as if one side is likely then the other side isn't?

The C++ Standard say about likely just *recommended practice* and *example*. See [[dcl.attr.likelihood]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.likelihood#2). So it is up to the implementation how they are actually used.

Though  *recommended practice* and *example* imply that only one mark is needed, and compilers where the difference is observed seem to imply this as well.

> Plus I don't see why % is heavy, it's just about reading bottom bits of number.

Only for a power of two. But it should be known that is is power of two in compile time. There's also a way to make this operation cheaper for a known not a power of two constant ([Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935/2945027)).

For a runtime value it is heavy, it is division.

It might happen that a value is known to the optimizer due to constant propagation though. Then optimizations apply.

Comment: "Only for a power of two" why? the same could be done for any number, just go to the higher power of 2 nearby...

Comment: @Algo - Seriously? 9 modulo 3 is 0, while 9 modulo 4 is 1. What's the algorithm now, pray tell?